# Is there a way to “hard-link” html code (links, form, buttons) with a video so that they are all displayed directly on facebook feed?

Tags: javascript, facebook, html, facebook-graph-api, html5-video

To give you a concrete example, kpsule.me manage to integrate into a video (but it’s in flash/swf) elements of interaction with the user(textual links, a form...).

When a user shares the video on Facebook, they not only share the "video” but also all these elements included in the video (link hotspots, forms…).

Example: http://player.kpsule.me/kpsule.swf?place=embed&ecoverID=1795281&typecover=none&openWith=undefined (then on the bottom click on the F icon for Facebook to share on FB).
(others examples: http://www.kpsule.me/fr/produit/?popin=248)

My question is: As Facebook only accepts to display directly on the feed formats such as mp4, or swf, it it possible to achieve what kpsule.me without flash/swf but with html5/javascript (send the video with included inside the shared group  textual links, a form…)

If you have any idea or wish to add to my brainstorming, that'd be welcome!

Answer (score 1):

This is not exactly what you are looking for with regards to facebook etc. But it's what I think you are trying to achieve. How well the result integrates with facebook I don't know. I've just seen it demonstrated on video.

https://popcorn.webmaker.org/

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Looks great.i checked it: do you know if at the end, you can share the total"video" (including elements such as google map...) as a youtube video ? i think yes but i am not sure